# Inserting two cells if the cell value does not match a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is supposed to check the cell value in column A first. Then, if the cell value is not equal to the row number  - 2, it should input a set of 2 blank cells. After, it should set the cell in column A equal to row number -2 and set the cell in column B equal to 100%. What happens with my code is instead of doing this everytime it happens, it only does it to the last cell in the given range.

```
Sub defaultValues()
    Dim rowPosition As Long
    Dim columnPosition As Long
    Dim counter As Long

    rowPosition = 3
    columnPosition = 1
    counter = 3

    For Each cCell In Range("A3,A18")
        cCell.Select
        If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.row - 2 Then
            Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.row - 2
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "100%"
        End If

    Next cCell
End Sub
```

Example Data Set, where the number 5 is missing so cells should be inserted and given the value 5 and 100%

CellNum-2   %
1   93.55%
2   93.38%
3   93.52%
4   95.75%
6   98.66%
7   98.34%
8   98.34%
9   96.08%

Thanks for any help that can be given

Comment: You´re not increasing cCell, so it´s not processing every row.

Answer (score 0):

Correct following code

```
For Each cCell In Range("A3:A18")
```